# kafka spring boot BeanCreationException

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

With in my spring boot service while trying to start a kafka consumer seeing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and unable to start the service itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int:channel id="inputToKafka">
        <int:queue/>
    </int:channel>

    <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
            id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
            kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
            channel="inputToKafka">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
    </int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5" keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500"/>

    <int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext">
        <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
            <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
                                              topic="test"
                                              compression-codec="default"/>
        </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
    </int-kafka:producer-context>

</beans>
```

```
package xml;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@ImportResource("classpath:outbound-kafka-integration.xml")
public class DemoApplication {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter")
    CommandLineRunner kickOff(@Qualifier("inputToKafka") MessageChannel in) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                in.send(new GenericMessage<>("#" + i));
                log.info("sending message #" + i);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

but i'm getting this error :

```
2017-04-29 11:26:51.034  INFO 6440 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/y/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2017-04-29 11:26:51.041  WARN 6440 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
2017-04-29 11:26:51.046  INFO 6440 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-04-29 11:26:51.064 ERROR 6440 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at xml.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:35) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.onInit(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:68) ~[spring-integration-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:155) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

2017-04-29 11:26:51.068  INFO 6440 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/workspace/springBoots/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.10/0.8.1.1/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.5/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.3.4/zookeeper-3.3.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/3.2/jopt-simple-3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.1/scala-library-2.10.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/101tec/zkclient/0.3/zkclient-0.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-integration/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-integration-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.1.2.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-file/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-file-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-http/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-http-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-ip/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-ip-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-stream/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-stream-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-kafka/1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-compiler/1.7.6/avro-compiler-1.7.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.6/avro-1.7.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-annotation/2.2.0/metrics-annotation-2.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/5.0.0/gs-collections-5.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/com/goldmansachs/gs-collections-api/5.0.0/gs-collections-api-5.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-java-dsl/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/yoavgo/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.0/reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar]
```

Can you tell me why ?

Comment: something is null in your setup, read the stack trace again and have a think what could it be - or just debug it